# Экспорт заголовков сообщений из Dovecot в базу данных

Tags: linux, email, dovecot

Имеется на Debian связка Postfix+Dovecot+Postgresql, и к этому всему пишу веб-интерфейс на PHP. Очень хочется выводить пользователям список писем (части заголовка from, to, subject, date, а так же название папки, в которой лежит письмо, может что-то еще) из базы данных, что бы "как в Яндексе". Соответственно, эти метаданные надо в базу данных занести - как? Писать отдельный скрипт, который по IMAP будет обходить все ящики, парсить заголовки, и отправлять необходимое в базу, или все уже придуманно до меня и есть соответствующий плагин? Или может сам Dovecot такое умеет, но я не увидел подобного в документации.

Comment: да, всё придумано много-много лет назад. протокол imap называется. [в php он внезапно тоже реализован](http://php.net/imap-open). там и примеры есть. подключаетесь, получаете актуальный список писем, показываете его пользователю. и база данных для этого — примерно как пятое колесо к телеге. собственно, imap-сервер, если очень хочется, можно рассматривать и как некий специфический сервер баз данных.

Comment: alexander barakin, спасибо. Да, с imap_open я знаком, и сейчас всё так и реализованно в "предпродакшене", пока UI причесываю и свистлки дополнительные прикручиваю, однако, когда на мой никому ненужный сервис понабежит пользователей, от тысяч imap-запросов, пусть и локальных от скрипта, ему определенно станет худо, как мне кажется. Почему-то хранение метаданных в базах у [Яндекса](https://habrahabr.ru/post/321756/) и Рамблера, а возможно и у всех топовых почтовиков, пятым колесом не считается.

Comment: конечно же, при запросе fetch не просматриваются мириады файлов. в частности, dovecot хранит информацию в индексных файлах для каждого пользователя отдельно. фактически, это мини-бд. по поводу яндекса и рамблера — полностью с вами согласен — dovecot им не подойдёт. они явно используют свои собственные реализации imap-серверов, значительно более оптимизированные под их-то объёмы информации.